# Facebook native app and facebook login

Tags: android, facebook-login

I wrote in facebook login into my app -

everything works great, except

if the user logs out of the native app, and logs in with a different user, my app still remembers the previous user.

How do i make it so if the users have switched from the native app, i get notified, and request a relogin ?

Comment: on logout button click clear all the user credential or make sure you remove all the data in SharedPreferences .

Comment: i am not asking "how to logout" i am asking  "how do i KNOW i NEED to logout"

Answer (score 0):

When implementing logout, call on your active session and use this:

```
session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

Comment: the question asked if the facebook app can notify me that the user in the native app has logged out or switched, so that my app can act accordingly